# Magento 2: Multistore view different language url key language switch page is redirect to home page

Tags: url, cms-pages, magento2.4.5, language-switcher, multistore-view

Magento 2.4.5 Facing issue with multistore view language change CMS page is redirecting to homepage.

We have two store view English and Spanish. Spanish store view CMS page name is add with Spanish translation, so when we open about-us page in English store view after switch language to Spanish then page will redirect to home page. But it should be redirect in **sobre-nosotras**(about-us) page in Spanish store view.

**For Example we have two url**

**English:** www.testdemo/en/about-us

**Spanish:** www.testdemo/en/sobre-nosotras

In above example when we switch language English to Spanish and Spanish to English then it will redirect proper store view page.

So any have idea how can we do this functionality.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!